# Issue validating input field. (js)

Tags: javascript

I need the validInput function to check if all input entered are numberic character/
The issue is when the first if statement return true, the function seems to skip the input check.
For example, if I enter 1 for input1, then "a" for input2, -3 for input3, the function will return true and shows the result.

https://codepen.io/regnagleppod/pen/NdWLYx

html:

```
        <label>Starting Number: </label>
        <input id="input1" type="text">
        <br>
        <label>Ending Number: </label>
        <input id="input2" type="text">
        <br>
        <label>Step: </label>
        <input id="input3" type="text">
        <button onclick="return playButton()" id="play">Display Evens</button>
```

js:

```
       function playButton(){
            run();
            if (validInput()){
                showResult();
            }  
        };

       function validInput(){
            var x = document.getElementById("input1").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("input2").value;
            var z = document.getElementById("input3").value;
            if((x == "")||(isNaN(x))||(x <= 0)){
                alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
                return false;
            }
            if((y == "")||(isNaN(x))||(x <= 0)){
                alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
                return false;
            }
            if((z == "")||(isNaN(x))||(x <= 0)){
                alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
                return false;
            }                
            return true;    
        };
```

Comment: Typo:  `if((z == "")||(isNaN(x))||(x <= 0)){` Should these not be `if((z == "")||(isNaN(z))||(z <= 0)){` and same for y?

Comment: I'm speechless..... Please downvote me to hell so I remember this next time.

Answer (score 1):

Mohit are correct,

Change the function as follows,

```
function validInput(){
            var x = document.getElementById("startingNum").value;
            var y = document.getElementById("endingNum").value;
            var z = document.getElementById("step").value;
            if((x == "")||(isNaN(x))||(x <= 0)){
                alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
                return false;
            }
            if((y == "")||(isNaN(y))||(y <= 0)){
                alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
                return false;
            }
            if((z == "")||(isNaN(z))||(z <= 0)){
                alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
                return false;
            }                
            return true;    
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code,please modified code

```
function playButton(){
        run();
        if (validInput()){
            showResult();
        }  
    };

   function validInput(){
        var x = document.getElementById("input1").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("input2").value;
        var z = document.getElementById("input3").value;
        if((x == "")||(isNaN(x))||(x <= 0)){
            alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
            return false;
        }
        if((y == "")||(isNaN(y))||(y <= 0)){
            alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
            return false;
        }
        if((z == "")||(isNaN(z))||(z <= 0)){
            alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
            return false;
        }                
        return true;    
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

your mistake is very trivial you are comparing <=0 and isNaN with the value of x, i.e input1.(value) , Change the 2nd and 3rd if (condition) it will work.

**Here is the changed code**

```
           if((y == "")||(isNaN(y))||(y <= 0)){
                alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
                return false;
            }

           if((z == "")||(isNaN(z))||(z <= 0)){
                alert("Please enter positive numberic character only.");
                return false;
            }
```